# строки из файла вставить в ссылку и в словарь

Tags: python, json

Доброго времени суток! помогите что бы скрипт брал строки из файла и подставлял в нужные места как на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import json
import requests


res2 = requests.get('https://yobit.io/api/3/ticker/tes_rur') 
res2_obj = json.loads(res2.text) 
vntxbuy = "%0.8f" % res2_obj['tes_rur']['buy']
#w = float(vntxbuy) / float(dogesell) * 100000000

print(dogesell)
print(vntxbuy)


print ("%0.8f" % w)
```

Comment: что вы хотите получить на выходе? Просто хотите вывести на печать, сохранить в словарь (другую структуру), etc.?

Answer (score 0):

немного продвинулсяДоброго времени суток!

```
import json
import requests

res = requests.get('https://yobit.io/api/3/ticker/btc_rur') # получаем 
данные ticker'а
res_obj = json.loads(res.text) # переводим полученный текст в объект с 
данными
dogesell = "%0.8f" % res_obj['btc_rur']['avg']


fa = 'pwr_rur'

f = 'https://yobit.io/api/3/ticker/' + fa
print (fa)
res2 = requests.get(f) 
res2_obj = json.loads(res2.text) 
vntxbuy = "%0.8f" % res2_obj[fa]['avg']
w = float(vntxbuy) / float(dogesell) *100000000

print(dogesell)
print(vntxbuy)


print ( "%0.8f" % w)
```

надо что бы переменная fa брала строчку из текстового файла
данные в файле идут в столбик. вот пример
введите сюда код
`cam_rur
cann_rur
uro_rur
opal_rur
via_rur
sdc_rur
start_rur
gsx_rur
vtc_rur
smbr_rur
etco_rur
xqn_rur
gml_rur`

пробовал по разному выдает синтаксическую ошибку